# Java image import

Tags: java, image-processing

What's the best Java library to use if I want to import graphics in some custom format (basically an array of bytes with a specified height, width, bytes per pixel and depth) and then work on it? Image resizing and cutting functionality would be useful if it was included. Should support saving to some lossless format too.

Ones I've found so far are too high level to import the raw data (or maybe it was hidden too deep...)

Comment: I assume you've followed the Path starting at http://java.sun.com/products/jimi/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found SWT more than adequate. It allows images to be manipulated 
at the pixel level. See [this article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-images/graphics-resources.html) and the [Image Analyzer](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/samples/org.eclipse.swt.examples/doc-html/swt_imageanalyzer_ex.html) example.

For more take a look at [SWT Home](http://www.eclipse.org/swt)

Comment: I'm not using SWT and I'd rather avoid pulling it all in just for the images. But yeah - it seems to provide what I need.

Comment: And unfortunately no... they assume picture depth == length of a pixel, but I've got 24b with padding which isn't loaded correctly.